# Memory map for Neo4j embedded

Tags: java, dictionary, memory, neo4j, heap-memory

When using Neo4j in the embedded mode (Java API), one can manually set memory map settings using the following API calls (or similar):

```
    GraphDatabaseSettings.nodestore_mapped_memory_size
    GraphDatabaseSettings.relationshipstore_mapped_memory_size
    GraphDatabaseSettings.mapped_memory_page_size
    GraphDatabaseSettings.strings_mapped_memory_size
    GraphDatabaseSettings.arrays_mapped_memory_size
```

My question is: Is the mapped memory allocated out of Java heap/extended memory or from the rest of the memory available. I know that for Neo4j server the latter is correct as long as it is run on Linux/Unix machines. But can someone confirm whether the same holds for the embedded version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows: from the heap

On MacOs/Unix: from the rest of the RAM

Embedded and server behave the same. That config for server is in `conf/neo4j.properties`

Comment: And does the mapping dynamically adapt and scale up, or do we have to tweak it manually to achieve best results. Let's say I have a rapidly expanding database, and I am doing large imports...

Comment: It is calculated at startup to use the memory available. If your database is expanding rapidly you might want to configure it upfront to use enough memory to cover that.